# NSIS reading 2 directory paths on 1 page

Tags: installation, nsis

Using NSIS Dialog Designer, I have designed a page which has 2 group boxes each with a directory input control.

`InstallLocation.nsddef` is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
This file was created by NSISDialogDesigner 1.5.0.0
https://coolsoft.altervista.org/nsisdialogdesigner
Do not edit manually!
-->
<Dialog Name="InstallLocation" Title="Install Locations" Subtitle="Select the paths">
  <CreateFunctionCustomScript>#Set currently saved values for the fields
${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0
${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt $R1</CreateFunctionCustomScript>
  <GroupBox Name="GroupBox2" Location="27, 148" Size="376, 68" Text="Select the second path. eg C:\PQR" TabIndex="0">
    <DirRequest Name="SecondInstallDir" Location="6, 28" Size="342, 20" TabIndex="0" ButtonText="Browse..." ButtonWidth="70" />
  </GroupBox>
  <Label Name="Label1" Location="27, 8" Size="424, 38" Text="Select both the paths." TabIndex="1" />
  <GroupBox Name="GroupBox1" Location="27, 64" Size="376, 68" Text="Select the first path. e.g. C:\ABC" TabIndex="2">
    <DirRequest Name="FirstInstallDir" Location="6, 28" Size="342, 20" TabIndex="0" ButtonText="Browse..." ButtonWidth="70" />
  </GroupBox>
</Dialog>
```

And the corresponding `InstallLocation.nsdinc` is as below:

```
; =========================================================
; This file was generated by NSISDialogDesigner 1.5.0.0
; https://coolsoft.altervista.org/nsisdialogdesigner
;
; Do not edit it manually, use NSISDialogDesigner instead!
; =========================================================

; handle variables
Var hCtl_InstallLocation
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_GroupBox2
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Btn
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_Label1
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_GroupBox1
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt
Var hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Btn


; dialog create function
Function fnc_InstallLocation_Create
  
  ; === InstallLocation (type: Dialog) ===
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation
  ${If} $hCtl_InstallLocation == error
    Abort
  ${EndIf}
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Install Locations" "Select the paths"
  
  ; === GroupBox2 (type: GroupBox) ===
  ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 18u 91u 247u 42u "Select the second path. eg C:\PQR"
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_GroupBox2
  
  ; === SecondInstallDir_Txt (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 22u 108u 178u 12u ""
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt
  
  ; === SecondInstallDir_Btn (type: Button) ===
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 201u 108u 46u 12u "Browse..."
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Btn
  ${NSD_OnClick} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Btn fnc_hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Click
  
  ; === Label1 (type: Label) ===
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 18u 5u 279u 23u "Select both the paths."
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_Label1
  
  ; === GroupBox1 (type: GroupBox) ===
  ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 18u 39u 247u 42u "Select the first path. e.g. C:\ABC"
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_GroupBox1
  
  ; === FirstInstallDir_Txt (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 22u 57u 178u 12u ""
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt
  
  ; === FirstInstallDir_Btn (type: Button) ===
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 201u 57u 46u 12u "Browse..."
  Pop $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Btn
  ${NSD_OnClick} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Btn fnc_hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Click
  
  ; CreateFunctionCustomScript
  #Set currently saved values for the fields
  ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0
  ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt $R1
  
  
FunctionEnd

; dialog show function
Function fnc_InstallLocation_Show
  Call fnc_InstallLocation_Create
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


; onClick handler for DirRequest Button $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Btn
Function fnc_hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Click
    Pop $R0
    ${If} $R0 == $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Btn
        ${NSD_GetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt $R0
        nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog /NOUNLOAD "" "$R0"
        Pop $R0
        ${If} "$R0" != "error"
            ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt "$R0"
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

; onClick handler for DirRequest Button $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Btn
Function fnc_hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Click
    Pop $R0
    ${If} $R0 == $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Btn
        ${NSD_GetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0
        nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog /NOUNLOAD "" "$R0"
        Pop $R0
        ${If} "$R0" != "error"
            ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt "$R0"
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

As you can notice, I have `CreateFunctionCustomScript` set as below for the case when I am pre-populating values from a properties file from which installer will read:

```
  ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0
  ${NSD_SetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt $R1
```

In my `.nsi` script, I am trying to read above paths into local variables like:

```
Page custom InstallLocation_Show InstallLocation_Leave
Function InstallLocation_Show
    #Initialise temp variables
    StrCpy $R0 $firstInstallPath
    StrCpy $R1 $secondInstallPath
    Call fnc_InstallLocation_Show
FunctionEnd
Function InstallLocation_Leave
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_InstallLocation_SecondInstallDir_Txt $R1
    StrCpy $firstInstallPath $R0
    StrCpy $secondInstallPath $R1
    #Ensure values are entered in both fields
    StrCpy $message ""
    ${if} $R0 == ""
    ${OrIf} $R1 == ""
        StrCpy $message "$message both folders are required $\r$\n"
    ${EndIf}
    ${if} $message != ""
        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONQUESTION $message
        Abort
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

So until user does not select both paths, a pop up will keep coming with message `both folders are required`.

However, it is not working as I am expecting it to.

Even after I select both paths, the message box keeps popping and I can not select `Next` to go to my next page.

I understand that this is because both the click functions are storing values in `$R0`. But I am not able to figure out what should I do in dialog designer such that the value of first path goes in `$R0` and value of second path goes in `$R1` ?

Have spent several hours now trying to figure out what to do in dialog designer or how to modify my `.nsi` logic to read both path correctly and to make my validation pop up behave correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${NSD_GetText} hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0` is missing the `$` for the HWND variable! Try `${NSD_GetText} $hCtl_InstallLocation_FirstInstallDir_Txt $R0`.